# Click on a Span element

Tags: selenium

i want to click on a span element ,DOM structure is

```
<td >
<a >  </a>
</td>
```

Once I click on td element DOM will be changing to

```
<td >
<input id=" ">
<span id=" "></span>
</td>
```

Since there is a anchor  tag ,every time when I perform a click on td element , it is drilling down and navigating to next page , How to Handle the scenario, 
using selenium ios driver

Comment: How it is related to Java? Java is not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

if you have this:

```
<td >
<a > SomeText </a>
</td>
```

and after clicking you want to get this:

```
<td >
<input id=" ">
<span id=" "></span>
</td>
```

i would do it using jquery:

html

```
<td id="someID">
  SomeText
</td>
```

jQuery

```
$("#someID").click(function(){
  $("#someID").html("");
  $("#someID").append("<input id=" ">
                       <span id=" "></span>");
});
```

this is probably not the best solution but it can do what you want.

Comment: Thank u ,it worked for

    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('SomeID').click();");